# Single Sign On - how to implement?

Tags: php, security

Say I have a network of websites. When a user logs in to one, I want them to not have to log in again on the other websites. Is there a secured way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do as stackexchange does and implement [OpenID](http://openid.net/).

That'd allow your users to sign in using one of their favorite services, and can be a two-click sign on experience. They wouldn't even need to fill out a form to register for your sites then.

Answer (score 1):

log in with [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login), another option.

Comment: You can use facebook with openid

Answer (score 0):

Create a domain name that you will use primarily for tracking your network users and use a web beacon image on your login pages to see if a cookie for your tracking domain exists.